# rendering/re-usable content in asp.net mvc, what are my options?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controls

In webforms, if I wanted to display a list of categories I would create a category control.  this control would either take in parameters or analyze the current url and list the categories and breadcrumb as appropriate.

What options do I have with asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Partial Views](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-and-the-templated-partial-view-death-to-ascx/)

You can find more View and UI Rendering techniques here:

[Views and UI Rendering in MVC Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123.aspx)